# Running 2 NEAT nets on the same observations

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, python, neat, open-ai

So i have been playing around with `neat-python`. I made a program, applying neat, to play pinball on the Atari 2600. The code for that can be found in the file `test2.py` [here](https://github.com/niallmandal/atari_pinball_tutorial)

Now based on that, I would like to do the same, but on a 2 player game. I have already set up the environment to play a 2 player game, which PONG using OpenAI Retro.

What I have no clue how to do, is run 2 nets at the same time, on the same observation. The way that `neat-python` works, is you get the observation from a single function that goes through each genome and runs the environment.

How would you create 2 `eval_genome` functions that can take in the same observation real-time? This means that they train based off of the same images and environmenrs.

Help?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this as I haven't played with neat-python before but I'm honestly curious, why do you want to do this? To compare the resulting network structures or something else?

Comment: I am planning to study the interactions between agents trained together. I want to see if they can develop cooperative behavior. This problem with `neat` is annoying though...

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with neat-python, but I have implemented NEAT to do openai tasks. If there is a class for initializing a population, you could just use that and have 2 objects like `population1` and `population2` and call them in the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to just train genomeN against genomeN-1 then you just need to loop through genomes using indexing and start at 1 so you can always do genome1 = genomes[ix-1] and genome2 = genomes[ix] and then modify your fitness evaluation code to run both at the same time and applies a fitness function to each. Also maybe you iterate by twos so that you only eval each net once.